# Outside of a total repaint, can anything be done about clearcoat rot?

Tags: exterior

One of my vehicles is exhibiting an increasing amount of what looks to be like clearcoat failure. Its that white patches or areas on the exterior that seems to multiply like a virus.

Outside of a total repaint, is there anything to be done?

Is it possible to prevent this type of problem in the future?

Comment: Could you post up a picture or two so that it's clear for all of us what these white patches look like?